# Coordinate system and scale bar units

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a custom map using the GMaps API and I now need to include a scale bar. However, I can't find a way of controlling the scaling and the units. In addition, I need to change the coordinate system, as my dataset is flat.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to start?

Thanks!

All my best,
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by your "dataset is flat", but looks like you probably need to take a look at [custom map projections](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#Projections) ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple)).